# Java MySQL Update Optimization

Tags: java, mysql

I have a code that are uploading player data from an entry to MySQL database. The query looks like this:

```
            uploadPlayers = getManager().getMysqlManager().getConnection().prepareStatement("UPDATE players SET name=?, ips=?, gamemode=?, lastlogin=?, timeplayed=?, rank=?, badges=?, level=? WHERE uuid=?");
```

And the method to upload the players looks like this:

```
    @Override
public void saveDataToDatabase() {
    try{
        for (final Entry<String, IPlayerData> entry : playerdatalist.entrySet()) {
            final IPlayerData pd = entry.getValue();

            SH.uploadPlayers.setString(1, pd.getName());
            SH.uploadPlayers.setString(2, pd.getIp());
            SH.uploadPlayers.setInt(3, pd.getGamemode());
            SH.uploadPlayers.setString(4, SH.getManager().getMysqlManager().getDate(pd.getLastlogin()));
            SH.uploadPlayers.setLong(5, pd.getTimeplayed());
            SH.uploadPlayers.setInt(6, pd.getRank());
            SH.uploadPlayers.setString(7, pd.getBadgesAsString());
            SH.uploadPlayers.setInt(8, pd.getLevel());
            SH.uploadPlayers.setString(9, pd.getUUID());
            SH.uploadPlayers.addBatch();


        }   
        SH.uploadPlayers.executeBatch();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

There is approximately 1500 players in the entry and in the database.
But it uses 15-20 seconds to update all the players every time i use the code.
How can i make it go faster and optimize it?

Comment: Upload the data into a temporary table.  Then do a single `update` statement using a `join`.  If the data is not already in the database, then `load data infile` is a fast way of getting data in.

Comment: Do you have an index on `uuid` column?

Comment: No i dont have an index on uuid column, but doesnt that only helps for select?

Comment: What @JiriTousek said is right , indexes do help with updates (looking up the row to update is made much much faster which often outweighs the cost of keeping the index updated).

Comment: Use JVisualVM from JDK or use netbeanas/eclipse and profile your code. Connection could be on autocommit but you are using addBatch/executeBatch. I personally use executeUpdate, handle batching myselft and then commit

Comment: Why a lengthy `uuid` as a primary key? A numeric index will perform much better than a string index. Besides, `uuid` is not always guaranteed to be unique though chances are negligible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an index on `uuid` column.

Without the index, for every entry in the batch the DB engine will have to go through all rows of the table to determine which row to update, giving you time complexity in the scale of *(number of rows updated)* * *(number of all rows in the table)*. With an index, the time complexity will drop to scale of *number of rows updated* only.

Adding the index will incur additional (time) cost to the updates and inserts, but it will be negligible compared to the improvement if you're always updating rows by their `uuid` (which you probably are).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here. As @JiriTousek has suggested not having an index on the uuid field is slowing you down (+1 for that answer). The second is you are updating all the fields is it strictly needed?

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update-speed.html):

> An update statement is optimized like a SELECT query with the
>   additional overhead of a write. The speed of the write depends on the
>   amount of data being updated and the number of indexes that are
>   updated. Indexes that are not changed do not get updated

The fact that the UUID field is a charfield and 9 characters in length means an index here would give a big boost. Even a partial index might work.

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) also says:

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this
>   and does not update it.

Despite this you shouldn't update all the fields (if they are not strictly needed) because you are passing a lot of data back and forth and binding parameters has a very small overhead too.

Finally if speed is really important @GordonLinoff suggestion of creating a temp table and then updating with a single statement is the way to go. If you find even that to be slow @GordonLinoff other suggestion of LOAD DATA INFILE is the best option of them all.

Comment: A good tip if adding an index isn't enough. More difficult to implement though, so I'd only bother with it if it's still slow with index, or if the amount of data sent between Java and the DB is of concern. This overhead only adds a constant time per updated row, not linear to table size.